# Django python queryset ordenar números de manera correcta

Tags: python, django

Estoy tratando de ordenar unos números con el queryset de django, sin embargo estoy teniendo un poco de dificultades.

Tengo una base de datos con unos valores de la siguiente manera.

"001","009","010","099","100","999","1000","1001","1009","1099","10000"

Ese sería en teoría el orden correcto, cuando intento hacer:

```
hola = Base_de_Datos.objects.all().order_by('nocliente')
```

Lo que obtengo es un orden de este tipo

001 009 010 099 100 1000 10000 1001 1009 1099 999

```
hola = Base_de_Datos.objects.all().order_by('-nocliente')
```

999 1099 1009 1001 10000 1000 100 099 010 009 001

Incluso utilizando .reverse no funciona bien el orden, la base de datos esta como CharField.

Apreciaría mucho una pequeña ayudita.

Comment: por lo que veo... tus numeros son unos strings.... si te das cuenta la forma como django los está organizando es por el primer caracter, en este caso va de 0 que es el menor a 9 que es el mayor, deberias tratar de pasar esos campos a NUMEROS para que pueda ordenarse correctamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas,

Si deseas ordenar ese campo como numérico, quizás lo primero que tendrías que hacer es valorar la posibilidad de cambiar su naturaleza. ¿Seguro que es un `CharField`? ¿Por qué no un `INTEGER`?

De todas formas, para obtener tu ordenación tendrás que hacerlo sobre un campo numérico, por lo que una posibilidad sería la siguiente:

```
Base_de_Datos.objects.all().extra(
             select={'numbercliente': 'CAST(nocliente AS INTEGER)'}  
).order_by('numbercliente')
```

Comment: Hola, recomiendo borrar el .all() por tema de performance. Desprecupate que va a arrojar los mismos resultados